# Strange crash in iPad simulator (<= 4.3) only (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) - any idea?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, exc-bad-access, simulator

Occasionally I am getting a really strange crash in the simulator only (<= 4.3). It happens when I press a button on a navigation controller embedded with in a popover. Under the popover there is an EAGLView which is rendering something. Memory is handled properly, etc... on device no problem at all.

Any idea?

Here is a call stack:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2c03, 0x00ab6707 CoreGraphics`CGColorGetAlpha + 17, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1cc9b72c)
frame #0: 0x00ab6707 CoreGraphics`CGColorGetAlpha + 17
frame #1: 0x00dc9871 QuartzCore`-[CALayer _renderBackgroundInContext:] + 97
frame #2: 0x00dc97af QuartzCore`-[CALayer renderInContext:] + 977
frame #3: 0x00dcf15c QuartzCore`-[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 444
frame #4: 0x00dc97e1 QuartzCore`-[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1027
frame #5: 0x00dcf15c QuartzCore`-[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 444
frame #6: 0x00dc97e1 QuartzCore`-[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1027
frame #7: 0x003434a9 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _renderSnapshotWithRect:inContext:] + 790
frame #8: 0x0067776d UIKit`-[UIClipCornerView _updateSnapshot] + 697
frame #9: 0x0067723c UIKit`-[UIRoundedCornerView didMoveToSuperview] + 51
frame #10: 0x0033c750 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1080
frame #11: 0x0033aaa3 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 57
frame #12: 0x004df1ad UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView _beginFastMode] + 259
frame #13: 0x003c0c74 UIKit`-[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) setEditing:animated:] + 249
frame #14: 0x0051453b UIKit`-[UITableViewController setEditing:animated:] + 73
frame #15: 0x003b6d1e UIKit`-[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) _toggleEditing:] + 77
frame #16: 0x0030b4fd UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
frame #17: 0x0051dcc3 UIKit`-[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
frame #18: 0x0030b4fd UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
frame #19: 0x0039b799 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
frame #20: 0x0039dc2b UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
frame #21: 0x0039c7d8 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
frame #22: 0x0032fded UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
frame #23: 0x00310c37 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
frame #24: 0x00315f2e UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
frame #25: 0x018f0992 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 1550
frame #26: 0x00f79944 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
frame #27: 0x00ed9cf7 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
frame #28: 0x00ed6f83 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 979
frame #29: 0x00ed6840 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
frame #30: 0x00ed6761 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
frame #31: 0x018ef1c4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 217
frame #32: 0x018ef289 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 115
frame #33: 0x00319c93 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1160
```

One more thing which seems to be important: when underlying EAGLView is hidden then it does not occur. GLView and Popover do not share any data - interesting, is not it? I suspect it comes when pressed button ("edit") wants to redraw/toggle to "blue" then some blending happens since popover heading is a kind of translucent. For me sounds like a simulator problem; anyone had  anything like that?

Thanks for any answer,

wl

Comment: Please, post also a code, where you get this exception.

Comment: @Aleksejs: Exception comes in "int main(int argc, char *argv[])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB gives me something like that:

```
    Alloc: Block address: 0x12387ff0 length: 16
    Stack - pthread: 0xa0014540 number of frames: 38
        0: 0x5fb8e in GMmalloc_zone_malloc_internal
        1: 0x5fd31 in GMmalloc_zone_malloc
        2: 0x60327 in GMmalloc_zone_calloc
        3: 0x60375 in GMcalloc
        4: 0x132a2d4 in class_createInstance
        5: 0xec65d8 in +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:]
        6: 0x48218e in +[UIColor allocWithZone:]
        7: 0xec63da in +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc]
        8: 0x4812c6 in +[UIColor clearColor]
        9: 0x15b1d in -[EAGLView initWithCoder:]
```

As we can see EAGLView is involved...

...and in fact after some digging I figured out the problem was to do with EAGLLayer background color. I declared it as follows:

```
    eaglLayer.backgroundColor = (CGColorRef) [UIColor clearColor];
```

This generally worked fine until then.

I fixed it with:

```
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const CGFloat clearColor[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    eaglLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, clearColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
```

or shorter:

```
    eaglLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

Since then no exception.

@chown: thanks for your tip.

wl

Answer (score 2):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash (probably from this line: `* thread #1: tid = 0x2c03, 0x00ab6707 CoreGraphics CGColorGetAlpha + 17, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1cc9b72c)`) and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: I got the following from gdb: 
'Alloc: Block address: 0x12387ff0 length: 16
Stack - pthread: 0xa0014540 number of frames: 38
    0: 0x5fb8e in GMmalloc_zone_malloc_internal
    1: 0x5fd31 in GMmalloc_zone_malloc
    2: 0x60327 in GMmalloc_zone_calloc
    3: 0x60375 in GMcalloc
    4: 0x132a2d4 in class_createInstance
    5: 0xec65d8 in +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:]
    6: 0x48218e in +[UIColor allocWithZone:]
    7: 0xec63da in +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc]
    8: 0x4812c6 in +[UIColor clearColor]
    9: 0x15b1d in -[EAGLView initWithCoder:]'